# Compute mean of big.matrix

Tags: r, r-bigmemory

I'm using the [bigmemory](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/) and [biganalytics](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biganalytics/) packages and specifically trying to compute the mean of a `big.matrix` object. The documentation for biganalytics (e.g. `?biganalytics`) suggests that `mean()` should be available for `big.matrix` objects, but this fails:

```
x <- big.matrix(5, 2, type="integer", init=0, 
+   dimnames=list(NULL, c("alpha", "beta")))
x
# An object of class "big.matrix"
# Slot "address":
# <pointer: 0x00000000069a5200>
x[,1] <- 1:5
x[,]
#      alpha beta
# [1,]     1    0
# [2,]     2    0
# [3,]     3    0
# [4,]     4    0
# [5,]     5    0
mean(x)
# [1] NA
# Warning message:
# In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Although some things work OK:

```
colmean(x)
# alpha  beta 
#     3     0 
sum(x)
# [1] 15
mean(x[])
# [1] 1.5
mean(colmean(x))
# [1] 1.5
```

without `mean()`, it seems `mean(colmean(x))` is the next best thing:

```
# try it on something bigger
x = big.matrix(nrow=10000, ncol=10000, type="integer")
x[] <- c(1:(10000*10000))
mean(colmean(x))
# [1] 5e+07
mean(x[])
# [1] 5e+07
system.time(mean(colmean(x)))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.19    0.00    0.19 
system.time(mean(x[]))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.28    0.11    0.39
```

Presumably `mean()` could be faster still, especially for rectangular matrices with a large number of columns.

Any ideas why `mean()` isn't working for me?

Comment: Can you provide your `sessionInfo()`?  I just installed `bigmemory` and `biganalytics` with R 3.2.2 and it worked without a problem.

Comment: OK, reinstalling `biganalytics` solved it. Not sure what was wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

OK - re-installing `biganalytics` seems to have fixed this.
I now have:

```
library("biganalytics")
x = big.matrix(10000,10000, type="integer")
for(i in 1L:10000L) { j = c(1L:10000L) ; x[i,] <- i*10000L + j }
mean(x)
# [1] 50010001
mean(x[,])
# [1] 50010001
mean(colmean(x))
# [1] 50010001
system.time(replicate(100, mean(x)))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  20.16    0.02   20.23 
system.time(replicate(100, mean(colmean(x))))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  20.08    0.00   20.24 
system.time(replicate(100, mean(x[,])))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  31.62   12.88   44.74
```

So all good. My `sessionInfo()` is now:

```
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] biganalytics_1.1.12 biglm_0.9-1         DBI_0.3.1           foreach_1.4.2       bigmemory_4.5.8     bigmemory.sri_0.1.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] codetools_0.2-8 iterators_1.0.7 Rcpp_0.11.2
```